# Cookie after append is null in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: .net, cookies, asp.net-core-3.1, setcookie

I have code that creates a cookie as you can see and append a value to it :

```
Response.Cookies.Append("rudeCookie", "I don't need no user to tell me it's ok.", options);
var AccessToken = Request.Cookies["rudeCookie"];
```

After appending, the value of `Request.Cookies["rudeCookie"]` is null - why?

Here is my `startup` file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
           
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddScoped<saamieServices.IComplicationClient, saamieServices.ComplicationClient>();
    services.AddScoped<saamieServices.IIdentityClient, saamieServices.IdentityClient>();

    // services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    // {
    //    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    //    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    //    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    // });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
            {
                option.Cookie.Name = "User";
                option.LoginPath = "User/UserRegister";
            });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
}
```

Comment: If your code is exactly as you’ve provided here, this is expected. `Request.Cookies` shows the cookies provided as part of the current request, and won’t include cookies written via `Response.Cookies` until your _next_ request—when those cookies are sent via the request. It’s confusing as you might well expect them to refer to the same collection.

Answer (score 0):

As I know cookie base on browser and be initialized after client's browser loaded.